# discord.py how to send a private message to a specific user

Tags: discord.py

I would like to create a command that sends a message to a specific user or to all users.
I tried to make this string but it doesn't work:

```py
@client.command()
@commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)
async def invia(ctx, member: discord.member=None,* ,message):
    if member == "@everyone":
        for server_member in ctx.message.server.members:
            await client.send_message(server_member, message)
    else:
        await member.send(message)
```

I've been looking all over the place though either they were very out of date questions or not useful for what I want to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can send a dm to a mentioned user like so: `!dm @mentioneduser test message`

```
@client.command()
async def dm(ctx, member: discord.User, *, content):
    await member.send(content)
```

To send a DM to everyone in a server.

```
@client.command()
async def dmall(ctx, *, message):
    for member in ctx.guild.members:
        try:
            await member.send(message)
            print(f"DM sent to {member.name}")
        except:
            print('Could not DM user, closed DMs.')
```

Comment: and to send it to everyone?

Comment: You would have to get all members of a guild using guild.members and iterate sending to each member. Check my edit.

Comment: last question if I can.
Is it possible to exclude some members who have a certain role?

Comment: Yes you can get ``guild.roles`` and write a check that passes if a member has a specific role name

Comment: Can I also define multiple roles?
For example I would like to define that if I write the number 1 it sends the message only to the members who have 3 specific roles while if I write the number 2 to other 3 members who have specific roles